# Does the flowing security rule resource.data.someArr.size() cause a read in firebase?

Tags: firebase

In security rules does checking against current data in the doc considered read free or is will this technical case the user a read since it is checking data existing in the doc ?

since I have and security rules that check if some array have a certain size on each action and I am not sure if just by checking it will count as a read ?

```js
resource.data.someArr1.size() < 6
resource.data.someArr2.size() < 25
resource.data.someArr3.size() < 25
resource.data.someArr4.size() < 65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the resource data is already available per any read/write request and stored as an object for old data, allowing new and old data to be evaluated - this does not incur any additional reads.
Additional reads are done through invoking data methods for external documents such as `get()` and `exists()` from security rules.
With this, only the last 10 documents are cached for re-use in the same query.